# How do I solve this 403 Error on Java Webscraper?

Tags: java, web-scraping, http-status-code-403

I am running this webscraper to try and find data about job values from Indeed.Com.
I keep running into a 403 error (: HTTP error fetching URL. Status=403, URL=[https://www.indeed.com/cmp/Critical-Connection,-Inc./jobs]) on the 1st site. Since its not even making it passed the first site, I tried to add a user agent. Can anyone provide a solution? Thanks!

```
package com.houarizegai.webscraping.imdb;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;

public class Webscraper {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("/Users/adam/Downloads/listofwebsites.txt");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        List<String> websites = new ArrayList<>();
        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            websites.add(scanner.nextLine());
        }
        File outputFile = new File("job_values.csv");
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(outputFile);

        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";

        for (String website : websites) {
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(website).userAgent(userAgent).get(); // Set the User-Agent header
            Element jobsCount = doc.select(".css-104u4ae eu4oa1w0").first();
            if (jobsCount != null) {
                int totalJobs = Integer.parseInt(jobsCount.text());
                writer.write(website + "," + totalJobs + "\n");
            }
        }
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

Since its not even making it passed the first site, I tried to add a user agent. Can anyone provide a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Apparently, they don't like your UserAgent, or they are using some other kind of scheme to detect web scrapers.  More and more companies are getting tired of folks stealing their copyrighted information.